# IntelliJ and gradle 3.0

Tags: java, gradle, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm making a mod for college computer science class and so far everything is integrated but Gradle. When I check the version via `gradle -v` it comes up fine, but as soon as I try `\mod\bin\gradlew` setupDecompWorkspace I get the error that it is not recognized as a batch file. This also happens if I even try to access the User folder in `C:\Users\User`.

I really need this to work to pass class, and nobody else in the class is doing what I'm doing by modding Minecraft. Short of paying someone to remote assist, this is my best shot.

Screenshots and advice would be appreciated, I'm modding for an older version of Minecraft.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that `\mod\bin\gradlew` is not an executable file. Try `\mod\bin\gradlew.bat` instead

Or give us more details, like the screenshot of the project/directory structure.